# "As well as" or "And" in the context

Tags: phrase-choice

There was this error spotting question in my homework

- "My mother **as well as** her friends always **go out together** at the weekend."

The answer is the verb "go", which should be changed to "goes", according to verb agreement.

However, I think the sentence's meaning indicates that "my mother" and "her friends" are of equal importance, because they would, as a whole, go ***together***. So, "and" should be used instead.

Do I get it right?

Comment: I wouldn't use _as well as_ with _together_. Either Mother _and_ her friends go out _together_, or Mother goes out, as well as her friends do, but they don't necessarily go together. Another badly written exercise.

Comment: *as well as* doesn't mean *and*, and in order to use *together*, your mother needs another subject of "equal importance" to go out (together) with

Comment: actually, that was a multiple-choice question, with the underlined text at "as well as" and "go".  With your clarification, I think I've got it now. Thank you guys so much!